# How would one change text in multiple elements with the same ID to translate it

Tags: jquery, wordpress, translate

I have 2 elements:

```
<p id="mdn-slice-product-page-display">3 makset 10€ kuus, ilma lisatasudeta. </p>
<p id="mdn-slice-product-page-display">Järelmaks alates 0.98€ / kuu, 0€ lepingutasu. </p>
```

Created by the same plugin on the same line, so I don't want to edit the plugin.

I found a solution to replace the text in the first one:

```
jQuery("#mdn-slice-product-page-display").text(jQuery("#mdn-slice-product-page-display").text().replace("makset", "payments"));
jQuery("#mdn-slice-product-page-display").text(jQuery("#mdn-slice-product-page-display").text().replace("kuus, ilma lisatasudeta", "per month, no extra cost"));
```

I have no idea how to target the second one. This will have to do until the developer fixes their plugin only, so does just need to work.

Comment: "*[Multiple] elements with the same ID...*" - this, right here, is the problem; an `id` must be unique within the document; this is true regardless of your desires regarding changing/updating the plugin. Have you looked at the plugin to ensure that it can't generate unique `id` attributes, or use classes instead?

Comment: I edited the plugin to add a class to these, so I can target those now I guess. Sadly the jQuery does not seem to work. Oh well. One thing at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. An `id` **has to be unique**.

You either need to make the `id`s of each item unique, or use `class` like so:

```html
<p class="mdn-slice-product-page-display">3 makset 10€ kuus, ilma lisatasudeta. </p>
```

The elements are then targeted by:

```js
".mdn-slice-product-page-display"
```

And then you must loop over the array found like so:

```js
[/* your jQuery object*/].forEach(item => {
  // do stuff
})
```